# Get the NSRange of string contains emojis according to UTF8

Tags: swift

How can I get the NSRange of string contains emojis according to UTF8?
My code:

```
let str = ""
for char in str {
    if let range = str.range(of: "\(char)") {
        let nsRange = NSRange(range, in: str)
        print("utf8 Count:", String(char).utf8.count, "utf16 Count:", String(char).utf16.count, "nsRange", nsRange)
    }
}
```

Result:

```
utf8 Count: 4 utf16 Count: 2 nsRange {0, 2}
utf8 Count: 8 utf16 Count: 4 nsRange {2, 4}
```

**Expected: nsRange {0, 4} then nsRange {4, 8}**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure why UTF-8 `NSRange`s are useful, but here you go anyway:

```
let str = ... // given a String
let range = ... // and a Range<String.Index> in that string...

let substring = str[range] // get the substring of that range in that string
// get everything before substring, so we can calculate the UTF-8 offset 
// of the lower bound of the range by counting the UTF-8 bytes in everythingBefore
let everythingBefore = str[..<range.lowerBound]

// create the NSRange with the lower bound and length of the substring
print(NSRange(location: everythingBefore.utf8.count, length: substring.utf8.count))
```

Doing this with all the characters in your example string:

```
let str = ""
for index in str.indices {
    let range = index...index
    let substring = str[range]
    let everythingBefore = str[..<range.lowerBound]
    print(NSRange(location: everythingBefore.utf8.count, length: substring.utf8.count))
}
```

The above code outputs:

```
{0, 4}
{4, 8}
```